# Android Retrofit Post Json Object

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit, retrofit2

Hi i am new using Retrofit and i am stucked for posting an json to the server.
        Initially i only had fields params with no arraylist in it . But now i have a whole json object which contains string,boolean and an arrayList.
        So i have created a pojo class by serializing it .The structure of pojo class is as given below

```
    public class SeekerProfileModel implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("_id")
        private String _id=null;
        @SerializedName("full_name")
        private String fullName=null;
        @SerializedName("phone")
        private String phone=null;
        @SerializedName("email")
        private String email=null;
        @SerializedName("native_address")
        private String nativeAddress=null;
        @SerializedName("fresher")
        private Boolean isFresher=null;
        @SerializedName("skills")
        private String skills=null;
        @SerializedName("resume_uri")
        private String resumeUri=null;
        @SerializedName("educational_details")
        private ArrayList<EducationalInfoModel>educationalList=null;

        public SeekerProfileModel(String _id,String fullName,String phone,String email,String nativeaddress,Boolean fresher,String skills,String resumeUri,ArrayList<EducationalInfoModel>educationalInfoList)
        {
            this._id=_id;
            this.fullName=fullName;
            this.phone=phone;
            this.email=email;
            this.nativeAddress=nativeaddress;
            this.isFresher=fresher;
            this.skills=skills;
            this.resumeUri=resumeUri;
            this.educationalList=educationalInfoList;
        }

        public ArrayList<EducationalInfoModel> getEducationalList() {
            return educationalList;
        }

        public void setEducationalList(ArrayList<EducationalInfoModel> educationalList) {
            this.educationalList = educationalList;
        }

        public String get_id() {
            return _id;
        }

        public void set_id(String _id) {
            this._id = _id;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getNativeAddress() {
            return nativeAddress;
        }

        public void setNativeAddress(String nativeAddress) {
            this.nativeAddress = nativeAddress;
        }

        public Boolean getFresher() {
            return isFresher;
        }

        public void setFresher(Boolean fresher) {
            isFresher = fresher;
        }

        public String getSkills() {
            return skills;
        }

        public void setSkills(String skills) {
            this.skills = skills;
        }

        public String getResumeUri() {
            return resumeUri;
        }

        public void setResumeUri(String resumeUri) {
            this.resumeUri = resumeUri;
        }
    }
```

And this is the 2nd pojo of arraylist

```
    public class EducationalInfoModel implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String _id=null;
    @SerializedName("profile_id")
    private String profileId=null;
    @SerializedName("grade")
    private String grade=null;
    @SerializedName("board")
    private String board=null;
    @SerializedName("percentage")
    private String percentage=null;


    public EducationalInfoModel(String _id,String profileId,String grade,String board,String percentage)
    {
        this._id=_id;
        this.profileId=profileId;
        this.grade=grade;
        this.board=board;
        this.percentage=percentage;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(String board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public String getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

And Here below is my RetrofitApiInterface

```
     @POST("/synkku/operations.php")
void createNewSeekerProfile( @Query("module") String module,
                         @Query("action") String action,
    @Body SeekerProfileModel body, Callback<SeekerProfileModel> callback);
```

And finally the helperclass of Retrofit

```
public void addNewSeekerProfile(SeekerProfileModel seekerProfileModel) {
        //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
        //Creating a RestAdapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Allconstants.MAIN_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter
        //Creating object for our interface
        RetroApiInterface api = adapter.create(RetroApiInterface.class);

        //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
        api.createNewSeekerProfile(
                seekerProfileModel,
                new Callback<SeekerProfileModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(SeekerProfileModel seekerProfileModel, Response response) {

                        //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                        //Creating a bufferedreader object
                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        //An string to store output from the server
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            //Initializing buffered reader
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
                            //Reading the output in the string
                            output = reader.readLine();
                            System.out.println("####data coming as success"+response);

                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"data"+output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("###coming exception");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Now the problem is that the data is not being posted
Any help would much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

use this instead of your InterFace ....

```
public interface RetroApiInterface {
    @POST("synkku/operations.php")   //removed backslash from url 
    void createNewSeekerProfile(
            @Body SeekerProfileModel body, Callback<SeekerProfileModel> callback);
}
```

and add these `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` line in your RestAdapter .... like below ....

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //these line is convert your POJO into JSON and Vice Versa 
                .setEndpoint(Allconstants.MAIN_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build();
```

**Note:- Always try to start Post Or Get url withput backslash and put backslash at end in your intial url eg(like this www.XXXx.XXXX/).**

**EDIT:- add these dependencies in your grade ....**

add the

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7' //this is same as Ravi told
```

> Above example for retrofit 2.0 and above liberalizes ....
>
> For retrofit 1.9 your all url is fine and RestAdapter also good

check you `onFaliure()` method and post here if any exception there .........

Comment: I guess he is using retrofit 1.9.

Comment: i also using query strings along with body @POST("/synkku/operations.php")
    void createNewSeekerProfile( @Query("module") String module,
                                 @Query("action") String action,
            @Body SeekerProfileModel body, Callback<SeekerProfileModel> callback);

Comment: @mdgouse What are you using retrofit 1.9 or retrofit 2.0(above)?

Comment: unable to import GsonconverterFactory

Comment: i am using retrofit 1.9

Comment: add this in gradle dependencies compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'

Comment: @mdgouse is you getting any error in Failure of retrofit ?

Comment: its coming success bt problm here with json in php..if($action=="post_new_user_profile"){  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); $fullname=$_POST['full_name'];   $phone=$_POST['contact_phone'];
 $email=$_POST['contact_email'];
$nativeaddress=$_POST['full_address'];
$fresher=$_POST['fresher'];
    $skills=$_POST['skills'];
    $resumeUri=$_POST['resume_uri'];
    $educationalDetailsList=$_POST['educational_details'];
    $obj = json_decode($educationalDetailsList, true);
 createNewUserProfile($fullname,$phone,$email,$nativeaddress,$fresher,$skills,$resumeUri);}

Comment: it hits the server and inserts null values into the table

Comment: have you check your url with POSTMAN . it give you success and failure and you get where is actual problem (front-end  or backhend).

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue.. The post request using retrofit 1.9 with the above mentioned code was absolutely working fine just that i had missed another @query string along with body in retrofit interface and the problem was with the php encoding json which i solved using  following line of code
          $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
          $fullname=$data['full_name'];

Thanks to all those who spent time trying to help me with this issue