# Send ROOM Database List Data in Body in Array through Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit, android-room

I want to send Room Database saved data in Body through Retrofit. I am saving data in list in Room and will send the same in body through Retrofit Networking Library. Below is the code of the same.

Room Table class

```
@Entity(tableName = "cash")
public class Cash implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
@SerializedName("UserID")
@ColumnInfo(name = "UserID")
private String UserID;
@SerializedName("FareAmount")
@ColumnInfo(name = "FareAmount")
private String FareAmount;
@SerializedName("TransactionId")
@ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionId")
private String TransactionId;

public String getTransactionId() {
    return TransactionId;
}

public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    TransactionId = transactionId;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return UserID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    UserID = userID;
}
public String getFareAmount() {
    return FareAmount;
}

public void setFareAmount(String fareAmount) {
    FareAmount = fareAmount;
}
```

Dao Interface

```
@Dao
public interface CashDao {

@Query("Select * from cash ORDER BY id ASC")
List<Cash> getCashList();
@Insert
void insertCash(Cash cash);
@Update
void updateCash(Cash cash);
@Delete
void deleteCash(Cash cash);

@Query("DELETE FROM cash")
void deleteAll();

}
```

TransactionDatabase Class

```
@Database(entities = {Cash.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 3)
public abstract class TransactionDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static final String DB_NAME = "transaction_db";
private static TransactionDatabase instance;

public static synchronized TransactionDatabase getInstance(Context context){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = 
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),TransactionDatabase.class,DB_NAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
}

public abstract CashDao cashDao();
}
```

MainActivity

```
btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cash = new Cash(str_userId, str_fareAmount,str_transactionId);
            appDB.cashDao().insertCash(cash);
            }
    });

   btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        
        List<Cash> cashlist = appDB.cashDao().getCashList();
        if(cashlist.size() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data is already uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
        // upload data code here
        }
        appDB.cashDao().deleteAll();
    }
});


public interface AppServiceAPI{

@POST("/Api/OfflineCashTransaction")
Call<ServiceOfflineAPI> cashtxn(@Body Cash cash);
}
```

I want to send data in body json and type will be POST as below through Retrofit.

```
[{
"UserId":"Test",
"FareAmount":"65",
"TransactionId":202008281139
},{
"UserId":"Test",
"FareAmount":"95",
"TransactionId":202008281140
},{
"UserId":"Test",
"FareAmount":"195",
"TransactionId":202008281156
}]
```

Response will be as below:

```
 {
"Status": true,
"Error": "",
"Message": "3 : Transaction  successfully Saved!!.",
"Data": ""
}
```

Comment: What is specific about this question? You can simply send your data as a  parameter of type `JsonObject` using Retrofit. There is a lot of instructions about it on the web. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435098/android-retrofit-post-json-object

Comment: @Sajjad the link shared by you only has question but no good answer and other than this I want to send the room database data in body. So will I put the data in Retrofit Call.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question. A nice practice would be to break it down to simpler/smaller problems and trying to solve them one by one.

Anyway use the method below to get the JsonObject:

```
public JsonObject listToJson(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = new Gson().toJsonTree(objects).getAsJsonArray();
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.add("my_custom_key", jsonArray);
    return obj;
}
```

To use Retrofit, you need an API interface like this:

```
 public interface APIInterface {
    @POST("your_sub_url")
    Call<Response<YourResponsePOJO>> sendData(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body JsonObject body);
}
```

This will be your retrofit client class:

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "your_base_url";
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

This is the POJO response you expect from server:

```
public class MyExpectedResponse<T> {
    @SerializedName("errorCode")
    public int errorCode;
    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    public String errorMsg;
    @SerializedName("response")
    public T response;

    //setter getter methods
}
```

And finally calling the API:

```
 public void sendData (JsonObject paramsFromRoom) {
    APIInterface apiService =
            RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<MyExpectedResponse<Void>> call = apiService.sendData("application/json", paramsFromRoom);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyExpectedResponse<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyExpectedResponse<Void>> call, MyExpectedResponse<Void> response) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyExpectedResponse<Void>> call, Throwable t) {
            
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why "my_custom_key" and where you converted JsonObject "paramsFromRoom"

Comment: every entry in a `JsonObject` has a name. So replace `my_custom_key` with your desired name (Server should know the name so it can parse the `JsonObject`)

Comment: where you converted  "paramsFromRoom" ? From the first method `listToJson`.